# Difficult sentence strucure

Tags: meaning, syntactic-analysis

> His thesis works relatively well when applied to discrimination against blacks in the US, but his definition of racial prejudice as "racially-based negative prejudgements **against a group generally accepted as a race** in any region of ethnic competition" can be interpreted as also including hostility toward such ethnic groups as the Chinese in California and the Jews in medieval Europe.

Can you please help me to understand the bold part? What is against a group generally accepted as a race?

Comment: *Generally accepted* is unfortunately phrased in this context. *Race* is not a very precise concept; here, the author means a group which ordinary public opinion regards as a distinct race.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can someone help me to understand this difficult sentence structure?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/255472/can-someone-help-me-to-understand-this-difficult-sentence-structure)

Comment: duplicate questions, or if you post two similar questions straight away, are closed instantly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change it this way in your mind:

racially-based negative prejudgments **that are**  against a group generally accepted ...

a group  **that are** generally accepted as a race (including the blacks)

Answer (score 0):

The concept of "race" is [contested](http://www.newsweek.com/there-no-such-thing-race-283123). Many, including me, will argue that there is no such thing as race.

The author is trying to avoid taking side in this debate by saying that even if "race" is a myth, the author's thesis is about **prejudgements against** specific ethnic or cultural groups that the general public opinion perceive as belonging to a "race".

This is elaborated on in the examples. The Chinese in California is identified by language, and Jews in medieval Europe is identified by religion - not by their genetic fingerprint.

> What is against a group generally accepted as a race?

Specially, he is referring to **prejudgement** against a specific group of people that are generally accepted as a race.